# Match records from 2 different tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have 2 tables (2008 mssql database), lets say x.dbo and y.dbo

x.dbo has a field name called "customer name" and y.dbo has a field name called "customers".. what I want is filtering the customers that match all and that match partially..(2 of the conditions together)

so here is my query:

`SELECT * FROM X JOIN Y ON 
UPPER(X.CustomerName) LIKE '%' + UPPER(Y.Customers)    + '%' 
OR    UPPER(Y.Customers)    LIKE '%' + UPPER(X.CustomerName) + '%';`

the above query gives *most* of the matching records but not all of them..

to give an example;
for these 2 names below, my sql command does not work although the names are similar..

`INSERT INTO X VALUES
(N'Şemsinur Akyürek-Senle Home'),
(N'Sinan Çetin Parlak'),
(N'Akyakadan'); 
INSERT INTO Y VALUES
(N'ŞEMSİNUR AKYUREK'),
(N'SİNAN PARLAK'),
(N'AKYA KADAN');`

what is the right code to match

Şemsinur Akyürek-Senle Home  <--> ŞEMSİNUR AKYUREK
or

Akyakadan   <--> AKYA KADAN

or

Sinan Çetin Parlak  <-->  SİNAN PARLAK

thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Akyakadan` will not match `AKYA KADAN` because it has a space. You can get around this by removing all the spaces from the name with `REPLACE()`

select 'matched'
where upper('Akyakadan') like replace(upper('AKYA KADAN'),' ','')

`Şemsinur Akyürek-Senle Home` will not match `ŞEMSİNUR AKYUREK` because `upper('i') != 'İ'` in Unicode. `İ` is 304 and `I` is 73. You can see this by running:

```
select 
    UNICODE(N'İ'),  --304
    UNICODE(N'I')   --73
```

This is the same for `SİNAN` and `Sinan`

Interestingly enough, `lower` will make  `lower('İ') = 'i'`. You can see this by running:

```
select 
    UNICODE(lower(N'İ')), --105
    UNICODE(N'i'),        --105
```

Also, regarding the use of `LIKE`:

> When all arguments (match_expression, pattern, and escape_character,
>   if present) are ASCII character data types, ASCII pattern matching is
>   performed. **If any one of the arguments are of Unicode data type, all**
>   **arguments are converted to Unicode and Unicode pattern matching is**
>   **performed. When you use Unicode data (nchar or nvarchar data types)**
>   **with LIKE, trailing blanks are significant**

So, assuming your collation supports `UNICODE` you can use `LOWER` with the `RTRIM` and `LTRIM` functions... and `REPLACE` to handle spaces

```
select *
from x
inner join y on 
    lower(ltrim(rtrim(replace(x.c1,' ','')))) like '%' + lower(ltrim(rtrim(replace(y.c1,' ','')))) + '%'
    OR lower(ltrim(rtrim(replace(y.c1,' ','')))) like '%' + lower(ltrim(rtrim(replace(x.c1,' ','')))) + '%'
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply scsimon.When I check my database's colation I see that it is Turkish_CI_AS so if I'm not wrong it does not support unicode.
So how can match SİNAN and Sinan in this case? (I gave up my intention to match Akyakadan with AKYA KADAN)

Comment: sorry for asking but how can I do that? (where is the "accept the answer" button?)

Comment: At the top left of my answer you will see a check mark and an up arrow. https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers